# Is there a way to order SQL query results by several columns?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

let's say I have a `purchase_transactions` table with fields: `transactionId`, `store`, `department`, `category` and `product_name`. I could make a sql query to obtain the number sales (`SUM(transactionId)`) by each product and store (`GROUP BY product, store`), and get something like this as a result:
[Unordered results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2qxJ.png)

However, **I want to get final results ordered (or clustered)** by `store`, `department` and `category`, in the following way:
[Ordered/clustered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IT3C.png)

Could anyone please help me with this? **Is there a way to do this in standard SQL??**

Comment: use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Sorry ORDER BY doesn't solve my problem. Results get order by one column but not by the others

Comment: share your sql.